# Cordova installation

Tags: cordova

I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not English so if you might have some understanding I would appreciate it.

In these days I was trying to install Cordova following the installation from DOCs but I ran into this problem:
when I go to create a new project with the command offered in the documentation "cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello 'Hello World'" I get the following error:

```
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js: 80: 10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js: 139: 10)
    at Module._compile (module.js: 616: 28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js: 663: 10)
    at Module.load (module.js: 565: 32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js: 505: 12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js: 497: 3)
    at Module.require (module.js: 596: 17)
    at require (internal / module.js: 11: 18)
    at Object. <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
```

Can you help me?
Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. I believe what got it working in the end was upgrading node and npm to the latest version then re-installing cordova.